# Upload audio file to Jodit

Tags: upload, jodit

I'm trying to configure my Jodit editor (v.3.0) in order to be able to upload also audio files.

I've put

```
$config['extensions'} = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'wav', 'mp3'];
```

in my config file and it stopped giving me the error "File type is not in white list", but it doesn't appear to execute any action.

What can I try?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you've closed the extensions array key with a } but I think is just a mistype

For the issue: I've figure out that the mp3 I'm trying to load is actually an mpeg file, even if the extension is .mp3

How to test: got to your connector, open the file connector>vendor>jodit>application>src>components>BaseApplication.php and comment out all the "if" statement with 'File type is not in white list' (for me is near line 365).

Now try to upload the file and you'll see the real extension. Mine was mpeg and after removing the comments to the BaseApplication.php file and adding the mpeg extention to the config.php the file was uploaded as expected.

Hope this can help you and a others (even my future me searching this issue again hehehe)